# How to bind a callback function in a statefull widget properly in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new in Flutter development,

Here is the problem:
The **Controlpad** is not working well when the `setState()` method is called in my function.

I am using [ControlPad GitHub](https://github.com/artrmz/flutter_control_pad)

My dependincies: 
**control_pad: ^1.0.0+2**

When I comment out the `setState()` line the ControlPad works fine but the widget is not updating, othervise ControlPad is not working well.

**Summary:**

I want to bind **_move** method with **onDirectionChanged** function

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:control_pad/control_pad.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.lightBlue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title, this.test}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final String test;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  double _x= 50;
  double _y= 50;

  void _move(double _degrees, double _distance) {    
    print('Degree:'+_degrees.toString()+' Distance:'+_distance.toString());
    //setState(() {      
      _x += 1;
      _y += 1;
    //});    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: null,
      body: Container(
        child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[            
                  Container(   //FullScreen
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    color: Colors.grey,                    
                  ),      
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: _x ,
                    left: _y,
                    height: 50,      
                    width: 50,              
                    child: Container(
                        color: Colors.purple,
                        child: null,
                      ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(                    
                    bottom: 10 ,
                    left: 10,                      
                    child: JoystickView(                                            
                      opacity: 0.9, 
                      size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/4, 
                      showArrows: false, 
                      onDirectionChanged: (double degrees, double distance)=> _move(degrees,distance),
                      ),
                  ),
                ],
              )                        
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I don't know what is wrong with this code.
Any help is apriciated.

Comment: I have the same issue now, were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

modify your constructor to:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title, this.test, this.onTap}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final String test;
  VoidCallback onTap;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
```

then call it like that:

```
MyHomePage(
   title: '',
   'test': '',
   (){}
);
```

my answer is based on your title, it seems you look for different thing in question detail